# Clojure why aset change column

Tags: arrays, clojure

I try to change one element in two-dimensional array with `aset` but it change column. How I can fix it?

I create `double[][]` array:

```
user=> (def z-buffer
    (into-array (repeat 5 (double-array 5 Double/MIN_VALUE))))
user=> (pprint z-buffer)
[[4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324]]
nil
```

Method that should change element:

```
user=> (defn z-buffer-check [x y z]
  (let [val (double z)]
    (if (> val (aget z-buffer x y))
      (do
        (aset z-buffer x y val)
        true)
      false)))
```

My actions:

```
user=> (z-buffer-check 2 2 6.6)
true
user=> (pprint z-buffer)
```

Expected result:

```
[[4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 6.6, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324]]
nil
```

Actual result:

```
[[4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 6.6, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 6.6, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 6.6, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 6.6, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324],
 [4.9E-324, 4.9E-324, 6.6, 4.9E-324, 4.9E-324]]
nil
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return new results when setting your z-buffer up.  So instead of using `repeat` use:

```
(repeatedly 5 #(double-array 5 Double/MIN_VALUE)))
```